# Как создать тест на PHP?

Tags: php, checkbox, тестирование

Есть тест на php. 
 
Делаю так: по умолчанию в обработчике php есть две переменные - $ot и $not - правильные и неправильные ответы, изначально прировнял их к 0, за правильный ответ повышаю $ok на 1, за неправильный - повышаю на один $not.
пример кода:

```
<?php
   $ot = 0;
   $not = 0;
      if ($_POST[q1] == a){$ot++;} else {$not++;}
      if ($_POST[q2] == a){$ot++;} else {$not++;}
?>
```

В вопросах с радиокнопками проблем нет, только один вариант. А вот в вопросах с checkbox не могу проверить правильность выбранных ответов.
Подскажите, как это реализовать в рамках моего примера.

---

Вот html код

```
<div>
    <p>1. ВОПРОС 1...</p>
    <input name="q1[]" type="checkbox" value="a"> 1</label><br>
    <input name="q1[]" type="checkbox" value="b"> 2</label><br>
    <input name="q1[]" type="checkbox" value="c"> 3</label><br>
</div>
```

А вот часть моего php кода

```
<?php
   $ot = 0;
   $not = 0;

  $q1 = POST_['q1'];
  foreach($q1 as $value) {
  .... 
}
?>
```

Вот что поставить вместо ... я не могу понять.
правильный ответ - 1 и 3 чекбокс, например.

Comment: Если выбрать несколько это будет массив. Сделайте вывод $_POST[тут имя checkbox ] что выведет, потом перебирайте их

Comment: foreach($checkboxes as $value) {
    // тут сверка
}

Comment: В одном массиве храните эталон ответа, в другом ответ юзера. Значения сортируйте. Затем из эталона вычитайте ответы юзера диффом http://php.net/array_diff и если дифф пуст, то верные ответы выбраны были. Затем из ответа вычитаете эталон. Если снова пусто, значит лишних пунктов в ответе тоже нет. И только тогда ok++.

Comment: посмотрите предложенный мной ответ, и если, можно, дополните его (я не могу понять, как в комментарий вставить код, поэтому в ответах написал)

Answer (score 1):

Базовый набросок решения. Можно улучшить.

```
$successCount = 0;
$errorsCount = 0;

$validAnswers = [
   'q1' => [1, 3],
   'q2' => ['London'],
];

foreach($_POST as $questionKey => $userAnswer) {
    //  проверяем, что такой вопрос действительно есть в списке 
    if (!empty($validAnswers[$questionKey])) {
        //  если не чекбоксы, а "радиобаттон", т.е. только 1 правильный вариант - всё-равно приводим к массиву
        $userAnswer = !is_array($userAnswer) ? [$userAnswer] : $userAnswer;

        $successCount += array_intersect($userAnswer, $rightAnswers);
        $errorsCount += array_diff($userAnswer, $rightAnswers)
    }
}
```